# $x^q < y^q \implies x < y$ proof

Tags: analysis

$x^q < y^q \implies x < y$ , $q $ is a rational number. For a natural number it is quite easy. We can show it by induction. As $x<y \leftrightarrow x*x < y*x < y*y$ and so on..But how could it be done for any rational number ? 
I guess it is only possible for $x,y > 0$

Comment: When $q=\frac{n}{m}$ can you not take the $m$th power (using $a^m<b^m\implies a<b$ for $m\in\mathbb N$ which can also be proven by induction)

Comment: Hallo Max ;) I guess you have to take it to the $1/m$ th power, right ?

Comment: What if $q$ is a negative rational number?

Comment: @PavelR. I am pretty sure that the "contrary" of the given statement is true for $q<0$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch i guess to q<0 it doesnt work. example take x=1 and y=2 and let q be -2

Comment: @Maths I suggested the following argument: For $q=\frac nm$ with $n,m\in\mathbb N$ and $x,y>0$ we have $$x^q<y^q\iff x^\frac{n}{m}<y^\frac{n}{m}\iff (x^\frac{n}{m})^m<(y^\frac{n}{m})^m\iff x^n\le y^n$$ So I taking the $m$ power but in the "other direction" if you want

Comment: @Maths Obviously it is always wrong for $x,y>0$ and $q<0$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch i assume it only works for x,y,q > 0.

Comment: Take log of both sides.

Comment: @irchans The way the question is asked I am not sure if OP already has the tool "logarithm" available

Comment: I would appreciate a proof without log. they seem to be more elegant

Comment: for log it would be quite trivial.

Comment: @Maths I have given you the outline for an "elementary" proof

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch to show that log is monotone increasing would that be enough: c>0 log(x)<log(x+c) <=> exp(log(x) < exp(log(x+c)) <=> x<x+c ?

Comment: @Maths Yes, but then you need to show that $\exp$ is strictly monotone (which is easy if you know $\exp'=\exp$)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch e^x < e^(x+c) <=> e^x < e^x * e^c. But why do i have to show it ? as it shouldt change the equivalence right ?

Comment: @Maths If $f$ is not strictly increasing then $x<y\iff f(x)<f(y)$ doesn't hold in general. Indeed take $f(x)=x^2$ as a counter-example

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch for &\exp'=\exp& youre using that the derivative is postive , which means the the function is montone increasing

Comment: Yes: Because $\exp'(x)=\exp(x)>0$ for all $x$, we know that $\exp$ is strictly increasing

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch this is an alternative definition of monotone increasing right ? that the derivative is postive ?

Comment: how could it be proven ?

Comment: @Maths My original statement was wrong. But the statement $$\forall f\in\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R): (\forall x: f'(x)>0)\implies (\forall x<y:f(x)<f(y))$$ follows from the Mean value Theorem

Answer (score 1):

Let $x>0$, $y>0$, $q>0$. Suppose that $q=m/n$ with $m,n\in\mathbb N$. From the fact that $x^q<y^q$ we get

\begin{align*}
0<y^q-x^q&=y^{m/n}-x^{m/n}=\left(y^{1/n}\right)^m-\left(x^{1/n}\right)^m\\
&=\left(y^{1/n}-x^{1/n}\right)\cdot\left(y^{(m-1)/n}+y^{(m-2)/n}\cdot x^{1/n}+\cdots+y^{1/n}\cdot x^{(m-2)/n}+x^{(m-1)/n}\right)
\end{align*}

The expression in the last brackets is positive therefore

$$
y^{1/n}-x^{1/n}>0\quad\Rightarrow\quad y^{1/n}>x^{1/n}\quad\Rightarrow\quad \underbrace{y^{1/n}\cdot y^{1/n}\cdots y^{1/n}}_{\text{$n$-times}}>\underbrace{x^{1/n}\cdot x^{1/n}\cdots x^{1/n}}_{\text{$n$-times}}\quad\Rightarrow\quad y>x.
$$

Answer (score -1):

$q >0, z>0$.

$f(z):=z^{1/q}$ is strictly increasing, since

$f'(z)=(1/q)z^{(1/q-1)} >0 $.

For $x^q<y^q$ :

$f(x^q)=x<f(y^q)=y$.

What happens if $q <0$ ?